# Dialog Box - Issue accessing Value inside Edit Text

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception

I have an EditText inside a  dialog box in which user will enter a new category. However when I try to access the value inside the EditText - i get nullpointer exception.

Execution Process.

There is a spinner for categories
When user selects new Category from the spinner a Dialog Box is shown to the user.

Code for the Dialog is as follows:

```
   //check if spCategories == new category
   if( arg0.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("New Category")) {
   //Show dialog box for adding new category
     Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddTransaction.this);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.newcategory);
     dialog.setTitle("New Category");
     dialog.setCancelable(true);
     dialog.show();

     Button btnAddCat = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAddCategory);
     final EditText etCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewCategory);

     btnAddCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
       **Log.v("EXT", "Category type is : " + etCategory.getText());**
     } 
                        }
     });
```

I am getting NullPointer exception when at the bolded line

Any ideas. Layout for Dialog is defined in an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
final EditText etCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewCategory);
```

is wrong, you have to change it in:

```
final EditText etCategory = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etNewCategory);
```

Without "dialog." your are searching that view inside the activity layout instead of the dialog.

Comment: Excellent - thanks - oddly enough i declared the button correct way using dialog.find...... - but didn't thought about the edit text

Comment: No problem Farhan! It would be nice if you marked the answer as correct, thanks!